# Format field based on number of rows - Report Designer 1.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, report-designer

I have a table in Report Designer 1.0.  In the 'File' column there are multiple entries with the same file name.  For each of these entries in the 'Total From File Header' column I'd like to replace the amounts with "N/A", except for the last entry.  For example:

Currently:

```
    File1     $655.12
    File1     $655.12
    File1     $655.12
    File1     $655.12
    File1     $655.12
    File2     $59.33
    File2     $59.33
    File3     $124.12 
    File3     $124.12
    File3     $124.12
    File3     $124.12
    File3     $124.12
    File4     $12.33
    File5     $44.64

What I'd like to have:

    File1     N/A
    File1     N/A
    File1     N/A
    File1     N/A
    File1     $655.12
    File2     N/A
    File2     $59.33
    File3     N/A 
    File3     N/A
    File3     N/A
    File3     N/A
    File3     $124.12
    File4     $12.33
    File5     $44.64
```

I tried the following, which didn't work.  Any tips?

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!AMA_FILENAMEKEY.Value)<CountRows(Fields!AMA_FILENAMEKEY.Value),"N/A",Val(Fields!TOTALPOINTSOFFILE.Value))
```

Comment: Sorry, the example I provided should be shown in two columns, not inline.  The File1 should be in one column, the $655.12 should be in the next column.  Hope that's clear...

Comment: You can edit your post to make those amendments - there's an edit button at the bottom. If you hit the button that looks like `{}`, you can format text as code, too, so you can preserve the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSetGroup")<CountRows("DataSetGroup"),"N/A",Fields!TOTALPOINTSOFFILE.Value)
```

I would prefer solving this in dataset (or sql) instead of formatting(or fixing) it in the report designer.

Comment: Thanks Anup, but it didn't quite do what I needed.  I expanded on my original example to hopefully better illustrate what I need.  Essentially, for every unique file name (which may be repeated x times), I need an "N/A" in the "Total From File Header" column, except in the last entry of that file name.  I hope this is more clear.  Thanks again for any help.  Jens

Comment: Are you grouping the data or just as it is from the dataset?

Comment: Yes, I'm grouping the data by the File name.

Comment: I tried the folllowing: =IIF(RowNumber("table1_Details_Group")<CountRows("table1_Details_Group"),"N/A",Fields!TOTALPOINTSOFFILE.Value), but it didn't work.  No errors, it just didn't do anything.